# Creates a default database in Firestore using Google.Apis.Appengine.v1 in C# library

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to create cloud firestore database programmatically using c#, but I am getting error when I run the code. How would I fix permission related issue I am facing? Below is the code and error

```
private static AppengineService _appEngineService;

public static void IntializeAppEngine() {
    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault();
    if (CloudManager.Credential.IsCreateScopedRequired)
    {
        credential = CloudManager.Credential.CreateScoped(
        AppengineService.Scope.CloudPlatform);
    }

    _appEngineService = new AppengineService(
    new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = CloudManager.ApplicationName
    });

}

public static void AddCloudFirestore() {
    IntializeAppEngine();
    var body = new Application {
        LocationId = "us-east1",
        Id = "projects/" + CloudManager.ProjectId
    };
    
    var res = _appEngineService.Apps.Create(body).Execute();
}
```

Error:

```
Unhandled exception. The service appengine has thrown an exception.
HttpStatusCode is Forbidden.
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
The caller does not have permission [403]
Errors [
    Message[The caller does not have permission] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]
]

Google.GoogleApiException: The service appengine has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is Forbidden. The caller does not have permission
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.ParseResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   at CloudResourceManager.FirebaseManagement.AddCloudFirestore()
```

Comment: Check if JSON credentials are properly set using your [service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38529162/how-to-debug-the-caller-does-not-have-permission). Then, check your project if you have [IAM permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42668030/no-permission-to-create-an-app-engine-application) to access the App Engine. Also, you need to enabled App Engine API.

Comment: Yes I have done that but, the error persisted. I am checking the link you provided to see where I messed the configuration.

Comment: Another reason why you're getting a forbidden error is because you don't have permission to get to the location. Can you try using Oauth, you can refer to these links: [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) and [Use the Cloud Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api).

Comment: Thanks Sarah,  I used the Google.Apis.Firestore.v1 instead of the appengine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Appengine, Cloud Firestore REST API can be used as Sarah suggested.
In c# Google.Apis.Firestore.v1 can be used to create cloud firestore.